# PHP. Загрузка файла с другого сервера

Tags: php, curl

Задача: скачать файл с другого сервера, указав в параметре запроса его имя (http://www.site.com/download.aspx?filename=filename.dot)

Использую cURL

```
$url ='http://www.site.com/download.aspx?filename=filename.dot';
$curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2');
$fileString = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_handle));  
    curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Получаю:

```
Array ( 
    [url] => http://www.site.com/download.aspx?filename=filename.dot       
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0 
    [header_size] => 0 
    [request_size] => 0 
    [filetime] => -1 
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0 
    [redirect_count] => 0 
    [total_time] => 29.999874 
    [namelookup_time] => 9.7E-5 
    [connect_time] => 0 
    [pretransfer_time] => 0 
    [size_upload] => 0 
    [size_download] => 0 
    [speed_download] => 0 
    [speed_upload] => 0 
    [download_content_length] => -1 
    [upload_content_length] => -1 
    [starttransfer_time] => 0 
    [redirect_time] => 0 
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array ( ) 
    [primary_port] => 0 
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0 
)
```

Хотя если открыть этот URL в браузере - то он скачивает файл. file_get_contents() тоже не работает.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: инфу вы получили, а файл то не сохраняете.....может попробовать так? http://expange.ru/e/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB_%D1%81_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_(PHP)   .... по вашей ссылке `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

Comment: Судя по всему запрос обрывается по таймауту. Попробуйте увеличить значения опций `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`/`CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`, либо используйте `0`.

Comment: @hindmost Internal Server Error и лог пустой

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Internal Server Error и лог пустой

Answer (score 1):

Проблемы могут быть разные, для начала попробуйте просмотреть ошибки curl:

```
//...
$fileString = curl_exec($curl_handle);
echo curl_errno($curl_handle);
echo curl_error($curl_handle);
//...
```

но, скорее всего, не скачивается из-за внутренней реализации отдачи файлов, т.к. ссылка на файл не прямая.